# Novice Programmers

Tags: discussion

Is this really a good place for programmers who are just beginning to learn? I've messed with CMS's like joomla and wordpress, but not a lot of coding is needed for those kinds of things.
I was overwhelmed with StackOverflow when I came across it, and even this section seems like its only for experts. Is there some other Q&A that caters to novice programmers? Or is this one different in some way that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I recommend finding a smallish community of programmers who do something you're interested in, and joining it.  On the Internet, that often means finding a niche (in my case, it was writing games and such for TI calculators).  Doing so can help you grow and meet interesting people.  Sites like Stack Overflow scale well and are great for getting your questions answered, but aren't well-suited for community bonding.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Answer (score 7):

You can certainly ask novice-level questions here, so long as they fit what is described in the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq).

The difference between Stack Overflow and Programmers isn't the complexity level of questions but rather the kind of questions that are asked. Stack Overflow is for specific coding problems (e.g. when you have some code and it's broken) and Programmers is for conceptual questions about software architecture, design, and (to a certain extent) software development as a profession.

Each Stack Exchange site attempts to attract experts so that people like you who have entry-level questions can find out the answers quickly and painlessly. So, feel free to look around the site and see if we cover the kinds of questions that you have on your mind.

Comment: Stackoverflow vs Programmers.SE is typically described as "IDE vs Whiteboard." This site does suffer from a conflicted purpose left over from its earliest days but people like our dear mods are working on that.

Comment: Thank you. That was just what I needed to hear!